# Exporting a promise to use in another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, es6-promise, module.exports

I want to eventually modularize my code to break up some of the functions I have in one of my routes files. I was able to do a promise chain that allowed me to get and use 2 pieces of data. However I have a total of 5 functions I need to run on the original promise. I will post the working code and then what I am trying to do but I can't figure out a way of doing it since the async I know is not called or executed in order. 
**EDIT**: This is my first real project I have learned through colt steele's bootcamps on udemy. What he does is gets his code to work and then refactor it into it's own file then imports that where he needs it. I am doing the same, because that is what I know so far, so I Have all my functions in my index which work by promise chaining. However I want to move them to my Marvel.js and use them all through out my project.

```
getCharactersComic(character)
getCharacterEvents(character)
getCharacterCreators(character)
getCharacterSeris(character)
getCharacterStories(character)
```

this is what's in my index.js

```
function getCharactersComic(character){
    var charactersComics;
    return axios.get('https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters/' + character[0].id + '/comics?limit=10', {
      params:{
        ts:  timeStamp,
        apikey: key.MarvelPubKey,
        hash:  marvelHash
      }
    })
    .then(response =>{
      charactersComics = response.data.data.results;
      return charactersComics;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('This is the error from comics: ', err.response);
    })


  }

router.get("/:id",  function(req,res){
  var character =  axios.get('https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters/' + req.params.id,{
    params:{
      ts:  timeStamp,
      apikey: key.MarvelPubKey,
      hash:  marvelHash
    }
  })
  .then( response =>{
    let character = response.data.data.results;
    let comics = getCharactersComic(character);
    comics.then(comics =>{
      comics = comics.find(Marvel.imageCheck);
      res.render('character', {character: character , comics:comics});
    })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('This is the error from id: '));
});
```

I would like to get all my functions in my Marvel file so I can call and use them like so even if I have to use all at the same time or not.

```
Marvel.getCharactersComic(req.params.id).
Marvel.getCharactersComic(req.params.id)
Marvel.getCharacterEvents(req.params.id)
Marvel.getCharacterCreators(req.params.id)
Marvel.getCharacterSeris(req.params.id)
Marvel.getCharacterStories(req.params.id)
```

Comment: `getCharactersComic` returns a promise .... use `.then`

Comment: I did in my router but I would have to do 5 {.then} to get all the data I need

Comment: why is that an issue? perhaps show what you want to do more clearly

Comment: Sounds like you want to call `Promise.all` on five promises, and use only a single `then`.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have edited my post I know it is now long winded but I hopefully described in detail what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Bergi using the `Promise.all` if I understand returns a single result of all the promises and I would go through them like an array, if I am understanding it?

Comment: @JasonGlenn - see how details are important. I thought you wanted to use the promise returned by `getCharactersComic`  5 times - but you want 5 different functions apparently

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple `.then()`

You could also have a look at `async/await`.
It is well documented at MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Hope this helps.